# ASP TextBox enconding using Data Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net, encoding, textbox, scaffolding

I'm using data scaffolding to create a web site starting from a Database but i found a problem with string encoding displayed by a TextBox.

If the string that will be displayed contains special character (like `<>èé` and so on) the textbox show the representing code as example `&#233;` and `&#232;` and not the character.

After some tests I discovered that its depends on what I bind to the Text property of the Textbox.

if I use `FieldValueString` it display code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="DDControl" 
TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# FieldValueString %>' Columns="80" Rows="5"/>
```

if use "**FieldValueEditString**" it correctly display the character

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="DDControl"
TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# FieldValueEditString %>' Columns="80" Rows="5"/>
```

Someone know why? What's the difference between `FieldValueString` and `FieldValueEditString`?

Answer (score 0):

FieldValueString automatically and necessarily does HTML encoding and places the value as straight text on the page.  FieldValueEditString represents that same text in Edit mode.  In that case, it generates a Text Box with value property set to the text.